# Concatenating distinct values contained within a string

Tags: panel-data, stata, data-preprocessing

I have a string variable (drugs) that contains a list of drugs prescribed at each line of treatment. I'm looking to create a new string that contains only the unique drugs from each line. In the example below, for patient 6, treatment line 3 would be "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE".

```
clear
input float(makeid line) str44 analysis_group
 1 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 1 2 "CYCLOPHOSPHAMIDE + DOXORUBICIN + VINCRISTINE"
 2 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 3 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 4 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 5 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 5 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 6 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 6 2 "PAZOPANIB"                                      
 6 3 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 6 3 "CARBOPLATIN"                                    
 7 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
 8 1 "CISPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                      
 9 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
10 1 "CISPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                      
11 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
12 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
13 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                        
14 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
15 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
16 1 "CARBOPLATIN + ETOPOSIDE"                    
end
```

I'm currently trying to tweak some code found elsewhere, but currently unsuccessfully:

```
egen newid=group(makeid line)
foreach n in newid {
local t `"`=analysis_group[`n']'"'
local t2 : list uniq t
replace analysis_group = `"`: list uniq t'"' in `n'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
split analysis_group, parse("+")
drop analysis_group
gen n = _n
reshape long analysis_group, i(n) j(drug_idx)
replace analysis_group = trim(analysis_group)
drop n drug_idx
duplicates drop
drop if missing(analysis_group)
gen n = _n
drop n
bys makeid line: gen n = _n
reshape wide analysis_group, i(makeid line) j(n)
gen analysis_group = analysis_group1 ///
    + cond(!missing(analysis_group2), " + " + analysis_group2, "") ///
    + cond(!missing(analysis_group3), " + " + analysis_group3, "")
drop analysis_group1 analysis_group2 analysis_group3
```

Comment: This appears to solve the problem, listing all distinct drugs administrated throughout each line. I'll test it on a much larger dataset over the coming days, but for the moment thank you. Really appreciated.